# How to check wcf service is connected with client

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-services

I have created a WCF service in c#. Iam able to access it form a client app with url `http://localhost:8080/classname/function`

Is there any way to detect whether the client is connected from WCF service in which the client has the url `http://localhost:8080` alone without class name and function name where the WCF service is listening to 8080 port at localhost?

Comment: What do you mean by connected? When a client makes a request to WCF service -- calling a method on an endpoint, the service processes the request and sends the response. At this point WCF service doest care what client is doing. While the method on service is being executed(executing) client is connected during that time.

Comment: By the way its not the service, its the client that connects to the service. Unless you have a duplex mode.

Comment: Sorry for the delay,  My question is is their is any possible way to send empty request to wcf service.

Comment: Yes you can send an empty string (presuming thats the defination of empty request) to WCF.

Comment: Can you explain how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Based upon your request to explain how to send an empty string message to a WCF service I have developed a VS2017 solution and uploaded onto the [GITHUB](https://github.com/Yawarmurtaza/StackOverflow.Wcf_Client_Connect_Check) for you.

The solution contain 3 projects, 2 on the WCF Service side (Class library and Console Application) and 1 for client.

---

**WCF Service Side**

First we define a `ServiceContract` that will have single `OperationalContract` to receive the string message and returns a boolean:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IClientConnectionService
{
    [OperationContract]
    bool Connect(string message);
}
```

Next, we have a class that implements this `ServiceContract`

```
public class ClientConnectionService : IClientConnectionService
{
    public bool Connect(string message)
    {
        /*
         * As per your comment on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43366101/how-to-check-wcf-service-is-connected-with-client?noredirect=1#comment74005120_43366101
         * the message should be empty, however you can pass string.
         * Once you are done with processing you can return true or false depending upon how you want to carry out 
         * this operation.
         */
        return true;
    }
}
```

Next, we have the WCF service host manager (a console based application just to host this WCF service)

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(ClientConnectionService)))
        {
            host.Open();
            Console.WriteLine($"{host.Description.Name} is up and listening on the URI given below. Press <enter> to exit.");
            PrintServiceInfo(host.Description);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    private static void PrintServiceInfo(ServiceDescription desc)
    {
        foreach (ServiceEndpoint nextEndpoint in desc.Endpoints)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(nextEndpoint.Address);
        }

    }
}
```

Its responsibility is to just keep the WCF service listening for incomming requests on a net.tcp port defined in the config file:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="StackOverflow.Wcf.Services.ClientConnectionService">
        <endpoint
           address="net.tcp://localhost:9988/ClientConnectionService/"
            binding="netTcpBinding"
            contract="StackOverflow.Wcf.Services.Contracts.IClientConnectionService"
          ></endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Once this is completed we have a running WCF service. Now lets turn our attention to the client that will consume this service.

---

**WCF Client Side**

This is just a console application that has a reference of WCF Service and it creates the proxy class to call the method on the service.

```
public class ClientConnectionServiceProxy : ClientBase<IClientConnectionService>
{
    public bool Connect(string message)
    {
        return base.Channel.Connect(message);
    }
}
```

Notice that we have used `IClientConnectionService` interface / contract from the service side. `ClientBase<T>` is a WCF Framework class.

Here is the program class that calls the WCF servie using above defined proxy class.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (ClientConnectionServiceProxy proxy = new ClientConnectionServiceProxy())
        {
            bool isCallSuccessful = proxy.Connect(string.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the client configuration:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <client>
      <endpoint
          address="net.tcp://localhost:9988/ClientConnectionService/"
           binding="netTcpBinding"
           contract="StackOverflow.Wcf.Services.Contracts.IClientConnectionService"
          ></endpoint>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

---

**How to run:**

Once you have downloaded the source code from [GITHUB](https://github.com/Yawarmurtaza/StackOverflow.Wcf_Client_Connect_Check), open the StackOverflow.Wcf.sln file in VS2017 (thats what I have used to develop this - not sure if you can open it in the VS2015) and hit F5. You can put break points to step through the code and edit it as you wish.

Hope this makes it clear - leave any questions in the comments below.

Comment: Thank u, I got information what I want. Thanks for your support.

Comment: @S.R.Bharath glad that my answer solved your problem!